# Sony Smartband 2 Beat-To-Beat RR intervals data

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Is it possible to access the raw beat-to-beat RR intervals data from Sony Smartband 2 API? If not, are there any other commercial wearable devices that can provide access to this data?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know of anyone getting good RR data out of an optical sensor.  Schorche claim something but I think it's heavily filtered so not very good for most standard uses of RR data.  You can get it from old fashioned heart rate straps using ANT+ or BLE although it's optional and I know some BLE straps don't do it and the resolution tends to vary from what I have seen for ANT+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about other wearable devices, but the Smartband 2 does not have a direct way to access it's data. The only data available is what you can pull from partner API's. Here is an article that goes in to more detail about how you can access data on the SmartBand 2.

https://developer.sony.com/2015/09/10/use-smartband-2-sensor-data-for-innovative-android-and-ios-applications/